# majority of the relevant group of MPs who actually vote on the matter v. a majority of all MPs who belong to the relevant group

Tags: united-kingdom

I don't grok the distinction in footnote 59. Can anyone pls illustrate it?

> Once it has been determined that a given Bill or provision falls within the EVEL
>   rules, the core principle enshrined in those rules kicks in. That principle is that legislation
>   to which the rules apply cannot be enacted unless it receives the support of a
>   majority of *all* MPs *and* a majority of all MPs representing *English* constituencies.<sup>59</sup>
>   This regime goes beyond that which was recommended by the McKay Commission,
>   since it enables MPs representing English constituencies to block legislation, as
>   opposed simply to registering an objection against it. It is therefore no longer possible
>   for legislation relating exclusively to England to be ‘imposed’ upon *English* MPs
>   simply because the legislation is supported by a majority of *all* MPs.
>
> <sup>59</sup> The majority must be of the relevant group of MPs who actually vote on the matter, rather than a
>   majority of all MPs who belong to the relevant group.

Mark Elliott. [*Public Law* (3 ed 2017)](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Public-Law-Mark-Elliott/dp/0198765894/ref=dp_ob_title_bk). p 258.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As in, there are 650 MPs but the number required for a vote to pass is not 326, but rather 50% + 1 of all the MPs who *voted*. Likewise, there are *N* MPs representing English constituencies, but the number required is not `(N/2) + 1` but 50% + 1 of whatever portion of that *N* actually *voted*

Comment: This is a relevant distinction because Sinn Fein MPs (of which there are currently seven) abstain from Parliament and do not take part in votes, so the number of MPs voting on something is *never* 650 (or at least, will not be 650 unless and until Sinn Fein no longer have MPs).

Comment: @F1Krazy Nor do the speaker and deputy speakers

Comment: @Caleth I forgot about that, but you're right, they don't vote either. So even without Sinn Fein, it still wouldn't be 650.